# "The older a tree is” vs. “The older is a tree"

Tags: phrase-request, word-order

I have this sentence:

> The older a tree is, the thicker its trunk is.

I’m quite happy with the meaning of the sentence. But doesn't it sound awkward to a native speaker? If so, how to reword it? I  feel that

> The older is a tree, the thicker its trunk is.

sounds better, but I cannot justify the inversion.

Comment: ""The older a tree, the thicker its trunk" is the usual way to write this but it is not a full sentence.  For a full sentence, your first is correct, with the **is** at end.

Comment: I understand that my sentence formally is correct. But does it sound well?

Comment: "The older is a tree" isn't correct word order in any sentence or phrase that I can think of.

Comment: @Lambie, may one mix short and long versions: "The older a tree, the thicker its trunk is"?

Comment: The second example might be part of a sequence like this: "I have two plants in my yard. The older is a tree. The younger is only a bush."

Comment: If you mean how it audibly sounds, you shouldn't go by that alone when learning a language. Sometimes patterns in a native language will interfere with different ones in a second language that you are learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is natural not to invert subject and verb in the clause that complements a comparative:

> The bigger *they are*, the harder *they fall*.
>
> The rarer *it is*, the more expensive *it gets*.
>
> The faster *the car is*, the less mileage *it gets*.

Comment: I understand that my sentence _formally_  is correct. But does it _sound_ well?

Comment: The sentence you thought sounded better, the one with the inversion (**The older is a tree...**), is  formally incorrect and sounds ungrammatical.  The sentences without inversion sound fine.  They reflect how native speakers actually speak.

Comment: It always amuses me when one says what you have said, which I also said and the question reposed twice by an OP.

Comment: @Serguei to sound good, and to be formally correct.